# pyinstaller: adding missing data from imported module

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I'm trying to package a PyQt application with pyinstaller. My simplyfied directory tree looks as follows:

```
maindir/
├── build/
├── dev_tool.py
├── dev_tool.spec
├── dist
│   └── dev_tool/
└── ...
```

When I run the executable file `dev_tool` from the `dist/` folder

`$ ./dist/dev_tool/dev_tool`

I get the error that it was not able to find `.../dev_tool/langdetect/utils/messages.properties`. However, when I manually add the `langdetect` folder (which I simply copied from my python site-packages after having `pip install langdetect`-ed it) it works. Now I read about how one can add files by defining it within the `.spec`-file [here](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#using-spec-files), however, if I try to copy the `langdetect/` folder from my Python site-packages to the `dist/dev_tool/` folder like that, it still doesn't work.

I added the following lines to my `dev_tool.spec` file

```
a = Analysis (...
datas=[('path_to.../site-packages/langdetect', 'dist/dev_tool/langdetect')]
...)
```

Shouldn't this copy everything from the site-packages langdetect folder to `dist/dev_tool/langdetect/`?

Any help here would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Tree` class from [PyInstaller](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/advanced-topics.html#the-toc-and-tree-classes).

```
# dev_tool.spec
langdetect_toc = Tree('C:\\[site-packages]\\langdetect',
                      prefix='langdetect',
                      excludes=['*.py','*.pyc', '*test*'])
a.datas += langdetect_toc
```

Then running `pyinstaller` with `dev_tool.spec` as argument will place all necessary data files from `langdetect` into `dist\dev_tool\langdetect` so `dev_tool` can find them at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
a = Analysis(
    # your other stuff here...
    datas=[
        ('langdetect/utils', 'csg_fileutil_libs/langdetect/utils'),  # for messages.properties file
        ('langdetect/profiles', 'csg_fileutil_libs/langdetect/profiles'),
          ]
    # the rest of your analysis spec...
    )
```